# Getting *.las file data into SAGA las processing tools?

Tags: saga, las

How do I get .las files into SAGA las processing tools?

Do I have to convert *.las data to *.sprm format first? 
If so, how?

Comment: Hi Ernest. Welcome to GIS SE. I see three questions in your post. What have you tried so far? Put some more details in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Download [SAGA User Guide](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/SAGA%205%20User%20Guide/) by *Vern Cimmery* and read *Chapter 11 - Parameter Settings for Point Cloud Layers*.

A short answer is:

- `Tool Libraries -- Import/Export -- LAS -- Import LAS Files`
- `Menu -- Geoprocessing -- File -- Shapes -- Import -- Import Las Files` (*see below image*)

[image]